# Regex pattern to match all tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write regex pattern to parse string with similar tags (3 chars) and those tags are retired in the string

```
ABC=TEXT 1 - HERE.. DEF=/TEXT 2: TEXT .. ZYX=TEXT 3 TEXT
```

When I use

```
#([A-Z]{3})=(.*)+#isU
```

I only get tags ABC, DEF, ... but didn't get content. How do I can get both?

I would like to get result with pairs tags and content

```
ABC
TEXT 1 - HERE.. 

DEF
/TEXT 2: TEXT .. 

ZYX
TEXT 3 TEXT
```

Update: See my example at https://regex101.com/r/uI0fW4/1

Comment: What programming language/regex engine? Anyway the rest is the second matching group-

Comment: I'm using PHP language

Comment: `ABC` will be in `$match[1]`, `TEXT 1 HERE` will be in `$match[2]`.

Comment: You don't need `+` after `(.*)`.

Comment: But I have empty $match[2]

Comment: Removing + after (.*) doesn't help https://regex101.com/r/uI0fW4/1

Comment: The `U` modifier makes `.*` non-greedy. It matches the shortest possible string, which is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a positive lookahead assertion.

```
([A-Z]{3})=(.*?)(?=[A-Z]{3}=|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uI0fW4/2)

Answer (score 1):

This `([A-Z]{3})=(.*)+` regex, specifically
this subexpression

```
(.*)+
```

tells the engine to overwrite capture group 1 as many times as it can.
On the last write, `.*` matched nothing because it can match nothing.

Thus that capture group is empty.

You could use this instead to get data in capture group 2.

```
 # (\b[A-Z]{3})=((?:(?!\b[A-Z]{3}=).)*)

 ( \b [A-Z]{3} )               # (1)
 =
 (                             # (2 start)
      (?:
           (?! \b [A-Z]{3} = )
           . 
      )*
 )                             # (2 end)
```